# WifiManager.startScan() - doesn't wake wifi if off, right?

Tags: android

The following will *not* turn wifi on, if the user has it turned off, right?:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(
    Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
manager.startScan(); <-- !
```

I want to make sure the wifi isn't being turned on (if off) when the above is called,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The above code will not turn on wifi.

You can however use `setWifiEnabled(true)` to enable wi-fi access. You will need to add `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` to  your manifest file.

Comment: The thing that worries me is that the startScan() method also requires permission CHANGE_WIFI_STATE.

Comment: I ran your code on my android phone, and no, it did not turn on the wi-fi. I imagine the reason startScan() requires CHANGE_WIFI_STATE is because, when startScan() returns a set of wifi networks, you can probably select one, thus changing wifi state.